# How to set import path of a zipapp in Python?

Tags: python, zipapp

I want to distribute a python app and let user start it with one-click.
But even I add path included all depended packages in the app, it will not work unless I move the packages to the top level.

#### The structure works

```
app.zip
├── __main__.py
├── lib2
├── lib1
    ├── lib_file1
    │── lib_file2
```

#### The structure not works

```
app.zip
├── __main__.py
├──lib
    ├── lib_file
    ├── site-packages
        ├── lib1
        │── lib2
```

Even I add `lib` folder into `sys.path`.

```
sys.path.extend(
    [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../" + p) for p in lib_path],
)
```

I create the zip app following [zipapp doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html#module-zipapp), and just want to include all libs so that the app will work even on a PC without python installed.

What should I do to make a all-in-one zip app?